# Is policy configuration supported for headless Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

Does anyone know how to setup policy for headless chrome?

I followed this guide  https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start.
I added URLWhitelist and URLBlacklist in the test_policy.json and put the file under /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed.

It did work for nomral chrome, but headless chrome didn't work.

So is it possible to setup URLBlacklist for headless chrome or does headless chrome have some ways to read policy config?

Answer (score 1):

Headless chrome isn't support policy so the easiest way to do this is using org-x11-server-Xvfb to run a full chrome.